# QGIS plugin - checkbox un-checked by default

Tags: qgis-3, qt

Does anyone know how to set a checkbox to un-checked by default in a QGIS plugin? Is it done within the UI script for the plugin and can it be achieved within Qt Designer?

Comment: What does mean un-ticked? Is it unchecked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in Qt Designer - it was really simple. All you need to do is select the check box and in the property editor under QAbstractButton there is an option to have the box checked.

Comment: If you've answered your own question don't forget to click the little grey arrow to denote a correct answer.

Comment: @EdRollason will do but I have to wait 2 days until I can.